# ValueError: substring not found Error when handling look up from a dict - geolib library

Tags: python, string

```
import pandas as pd
import pygeohash as gh
from geolib import geohash

geo_dict = {'9q5dx': 10, '9q9hv': 15, '9q5dv': 20}


df = pd.DataFrame({'geohash': ['9q5dx','9qh0g','9q9hv','9q5dv'],
                   'label': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

try:
    
    df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x : geo_dict[x.geohash], axis=1)
    
except Exception as e:
    
    g = str(e)
    
    print(g, type(g))
    
    neighbours = geohash.neighbours(g)
```

Based on the [documentation](https://geolib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the `geohash.neighbours` function accepts a geohash string and returns a named tuple. However, I am getting an error when passing a string geohash.

```
'9qh0g' <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-488-e803623c09eb> in <module>
     18     print(g, type(g))
     19 
---> 20     neighbours = geohash.neighbours(g)
     21 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geolib/geohash.py in neighbours(geohash)
    254     >>> gcpuypm
    255     """
--> 256     n = adjacent(geohash, 'n')
    257     ne = adjacent(n, 'e')
    258     e = adjacent(geohash, 'e')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geolib/geohash.py in adjacent(geohash, direction)
    232         parent = adjacent(parent, direction)
    233 
--> 234     index = neighbour[direction][typ].index(last_char)
    235     return parent + base32[index]
    236 

    ValueError: substring not found
```

When I hard code it, I get the expect result:

```
geohash.neighbours('9qh0g')

Neighbours(n='9qh15', ne='9qh1h', e='9qh0u', se='9qh0s', s='9qh0e', sw='9qh0d', w='9qh0f', nw='9qh14')
```